# Redirect incoming search request to other domain (also with bolt.cm)

Tags: php, redirect, bolt-cms

I have two websites running on Bolt.cm

One what older website is called `blog.domain.nl` and the other one just `domain.nl`

Now i made some similar posts on `domain.nl` (note this a diferente bolt.cm installation)

I want to redirect direct hits on `blog.domain.nl` to  `domain.nl`
I would like to unpublish the posts on `blog.domain.nl`

How can I setup a proper direct for this?

So that if google has a search index for `blog.domain.nl/a/blog`. I want to redirect it to `domain.nl/a/blog`

Comment: thats why i always advocate to learn core language first than framwork .. you can do it by dom  http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php and parse it  and add it your database

Answer (score 0):

There is a redirect extension for Bolt that can be found here: http://extensions.bolt.cm/view/d325689f-ace6-4700-bffd-1197d9c0cec8

The part of the configuration you need is described here:
https://github.com/foundrycode/boltredirector#using-wildcards

If your needs are only as simple as the one example you gave, then this would be unnecessary and you could just use a mod_rewrite redirect (assuming you are using Apache), this would look something like this...

```
RewriteRule ^blog/$ http://domain.nl/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```